# Elasticsearch Query with And & Or in the Same Query - Bool Query?

Tags: java, sql, elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search

I am using elastic 2.2, and Sense.

I have the following question to clarify one way I am thinking.

Elasticsearch is a Full  Text Search Engine and not a SQL Database, however it is still possible to think in ES queries in terms of algebra(AND, OR, WHERE, etc).

I don't care about score in this regard.

Assuming I have the following flat Document Type Customers, where all fields are **not_analysed**, properties in the Mapping are:

```
"properties": {
          "address": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "age": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "customerid": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "firstname": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "lastname": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "updated": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "date_hour_minute_second_millis"
          }
        }
```

Now I Index:

```
PUT customers_ds/customers/1
{
  "customerid": "1",
  "firstname": "Marie",
  "address": "Brazil",
  "updated": "2017-01-13T02:36:37.292",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "age": 20 
}



PUT customers_ds/customers/2
{
  "customerid": "1",
  "firstname": "John",
  "address": "North America",
  "updated": "2017-01-13T02:36:37.292",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "age": 25 
}
```

---

What query should I write to say:

I want all customers where the first Name is Marie, or they live in "North America"

```
select * from customers where firstname = "Marie" or address = "North America"
```

How to write such ES query?

And Finally, how to write:

```
select * from customers where firstname = "Marie" and lastname = "Doe" or address = "North America"
```

In this last query I want to get back from ES:

Mary and John, because of the OR. Or address = "North America", while Mary will Match in the AND. Let me know if this is clear.

**???**

Comment: "where all fields are analysed" => all string fields in your mapping are `not_analyzed`. Can you clarify?

Comment: HI @Val - I meant where all fields are not analysed. I am editing it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an OR query you can do it like this:

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "minimum_should_match": 1,
         "should": [
            {
               "term": {
                  "firstname": "Marie"
               }
            },
            {
               "term": {
                  "address": "North America"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

If you want an AND query you can simply replace `should` with `filter` (or `must` if you care about score):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "firstname": "Marie"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "lastname": "Doe"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "address": "North America"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Val - yes, and if I want AND with OR in the same query:

select * from customers where firstname = "Marie" and lastname = "Doe" or address = "North America"

So I should get back in this example, Marie, and JOhn, because John has lastname = Doe, and lives in North America, that's OR

Comment: Would you know how to then get the AND and OR in the same query, like in the example above?

Comment: That's what I did in the second query

Comment: Ok @Val, but I don't see the 2 documents by running this query, only Marie comes back. I am expecting to see John as well (  OR address = "North America" )_____ The second query only gives me Mary, address is "Brazil".

Comment: I've added `"minimum_should_match": 1`, please try again

Comment: Still does not return, I have checked my Index, the JSON structure is flat, the fields are all not_analyzed.

Comment: I've revised the query, please try again

Comment: HI @Val, now it works, and also works without the minimum_should_match. Why did you have to wrap the whole query into a should? Without that it is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

For OR query use filter we you dont take score for concern

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "term" : { "firstname" : "Marie" }
        },
        "filter" : {
            "or" : [
                {
                    "term" : { "address" : "north america" }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```